# Newbie question to standard deviation of paired t test

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval

I am doing a study of on effects of intervention A,B and non intervention on same group of subject ( will go througb all 3 and do a before and after result)

After which i only have the sample mean and standard deviation of A,B and non-intervention.

If i want to compare

1. Effect of non-intervention against intervention (A+B)
2. Effect of A vs B

How do i calculate the standard deviation of the difference for each case?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify: By "on the same group of subjects" do you mean that for every participant you will have measurements before either intervention, after intervention A and after intervention B? If yes, then how do you randomize the order of A and B for a given subject?

Comment: @dipetkov For the first statement, you are right. For the second statement of random, I do not have fixed method and just have a period of washout to eliminate influence of treatment in between treatment

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to look at is testing for contrasts in linear models. See [this link](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat555/node/73/) for a starting point